# fake.date_between return always the same date in a loop

Tags: django, django-migrations, faker

I try to implement an algo to create Django objects with random date over the last 2 years

I use Faker and it work when I use it in a python shell: each time I call fake.date_between(start_date='today', end_date='+2y') it retunr a new datetime object

but I want to do the same in django data migration but don't nderstand why it always return the same value

```
fake = Faker()

for order in range(0,total_orders + 1):
        Orders.objects.create(
            table = random.sample(tables,k=1)[0],
            customers = random.randrange(1,6),
            split_bill = random.randrange(1,3),
            delivered = True,
            paid = True,
            created_at = fake.date_between(start_date='today', end_date='+2y')
        )
```

save `2020-12-16 17:57:04.203858+01` in postgresql database

Comment: you should show the line where you define fake, otherwise it is hard to know where the error is. I would assume that the brackets are missing fake.date()_between(..

Comment: there is no error when I set created_at with fake date... and I tried fake.date()_between(start_date='today', end_date='+2y') but it is not the correct syntax

Comment: I also try using fake.date_time_between but dose the same

Comment: Iunderstand the problem: created_at is an auto_now_add... so when created it is set with server date